# how to apply isnull to variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

I have table called sample with columns:

```
Id, Name, Dept, active
```

Query:

```
select Id 
from Sample 
where Dept = @Dept and active = 1
```

I want to fetch id from sample table name by passing `deptment` name whose is active. There can come situation where where I get 2 records. Two dept might be active. That's why I am taking top 1. Some time might not come any record.

That's why I used like this in stored procedure:

```
declare @TempId int      

set top 1 @TempId  = Id 
from Sample 
where Dept = @Dept and active = 1

if(@TempId is null)
begin
    @TempId = 0
end
```

Can I use `isnull` in the above select instead of after which is suitable for both my conditions?

Comment: HINT : `declare @TempId int =0 `

Answer (score 2):

No. First it must be `select`, not `set`.
And if `select` returns no rows, @TempId will not be changed. See this simple example

```
declare @TempId int = 0;
select @TempId = null where 1=2;
select @TempId;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write following code:

```
DECLARE @TempId int =
    COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM [Sample] WHERE Dept = @dept AND Active=1), 0)
```

If no rows are returned, NULL coalescing function is used.

Answer (score -1):

At the time of selecting record, check for the NULL value, and select the record which is NOT NULL.

declare @TempId int
    select top 1 @TempId  = Id from Sample where Dept = @Dept and active = 1 and Id is not null

Comment: This is completely wrong. As the OP says, sometimes no results are returned, not some contain a null.